# Node.js app runs locally but fails on docker (sh: 1: rimraf: not found)

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, containers

I am able to build the docker image but can't get the container to run. Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "linked-versions-viewer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "type": "module",

  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build_only": "rollup -c",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run clean && npm run build_only",
    "serve": "parcel src/index.html --port 12345",
    "start": "npm run clean && npm run serve"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "author": "...",
  "license": "...",
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.12.3",
    "base-widget": "...",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.28",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "rev-hash": "^3.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.39.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.29.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^6.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.17.0 as base

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

FROM base as production

ENV NODE_PATH=./build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I created the image by running `docker build -t testapp .` and tried running the container with `docker run -p 8080:8080 -d testapp` but it keeps immediately exiting with code 1. This is the error log for the image:

```
> linked-versions-viewer@1.0.0 start /app
> npm run clean && npm run serve


> linked-versions-viewer@1.0.0 clean /app
> rimraf dist

sh: 1: rimraf: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! linked-versions-viewer@1.0.0 clean: `rimraf dist`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the linked-versions-viewer@1.0.0 clean script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-06-09T20_40_17_204Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! linked-versions-viewer@1.0.0 start: `npm run clean && npm run serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the linked-versions-viewer@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried just removing the rimraf dependency altogether but then got a similar error for the parcel dependency, so maybe the packages aren't being installed properly? The app is also written in typescript if that's helpful.

Not sure what to try next. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: How are you starting the container?  (Are you using a `docker run -v` option or Compose `volumes:` to hide everything in the image's `/app` directory?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm using 'docker-compose build' and then 'docker-compose up -d'

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @DavidMaze done

Comment: Yeah, the `volumes:` block is hiding everything that the Dockerfile does.  You should be able to delete that block to run the code that's built into the image.  (You shouldn't need `expose:` or `command:` since they duplicate the standard image metadata, and Compose can provide its own `container_name:`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I removed the volumes block and everything after it but the container kept exiting immediately after it started so I added 'command: tail -f /dev/null' and that seems to work. Is it okay to run it like that in a production environment?

Comment: No, you should never need that.  That `tail` process does nothing and run in place of the standard container command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233528/discussion-between-msam-and-david-maze).

Comment: What is the error you see now? Could you update your question with latest setup and also could you remove the “command” you have given inside docker-compose as well.

Comment: @ErangaHeshan I updated the question with my latest error logs and dockerfile. I would like to run the container with just the dockerfile and want to figure out why I keep getting the rimraf error. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Form [`npm install` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install),

> With the `--production` flag (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `production`), npm will not install modules listed in `devDependencies`

Since you have `ENV NODE_ENV=production` in your `base` image, neither `rimraf` nor `parcel-bundler` is installed inside your container.

Your `npm start` command is running `npm run clean && npm run serve`. `npm run clean` uses `rimraf` module and `npm run serve` uses `parcel-bundler` module. This is the reason why you're seeing both the errors.

You can try one of the following solutions,

1. Remove `ENV NODE_ENV=production` from your Dockerfile (This is the quickest solution but should not be used in production)
2. You can install `rimraf` and `parcel-bundler` globally inside the container using:

   ```sh
   RUN npm install --global rimraf && npm install --global parcel-bundler
   ```

   However, I still don't think this is a good production-ready setup.
3. You can properly build your app using `npm run build` inside your container and serve it. However, I am not familiar with React enough to help you set up this on Docker.